# Ionic / AngularJS passing ID through a http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble passing the session_id through to my http.get function, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Heres my controller:

```js
.controller('feedCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$ionicHistory,$state,$http) {

    $scope.session_id= sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');
    if($scope.session_id == null){
        $state.go('login');
    }
    else {
        $http.get('https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php?id='+ $scope.session_id +).then(function(rest) {
            $scope.records = rest.data;
        });
    }
    
})
```

Comment: could you add some more details? for example how do you store the session_id at first?

Comment: Sessions are stored in the Login Controller via 

`$scope.user_details = response.records;
                sessionStorage.setItem('session_id', $scope.user_details.session_id);
                sessionStorage.setItem('session_username', $scope.user_details.session_username );
                sessionStorage.setItem('session_email', $scope.user_details.session_email);`

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors I see in the code:

You should do to inject `sessionStorage` service.
Delete `+` at the end of URL.

Check Example : [Link](https://medium.com/@petehouston/awesome-local-storage-for-ionic-with-ngstorage-c11c0284d658#.8hbpjtab6)

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm new to Ionic and angularjs

Comment: This is working, however on the PHP Server side. using `$_GET['id']` its not fetching the ID. I can see in the log that on the controller's get function that the ID is in the url

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt exactly know what is the problem unless u explain how 'https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/' endpoint works and what error does it produce but my suspicion is that as you say you need to PASS the session_id and not GET it, you need to use $http.post instead of $http.get

Comment: Aah your right, thats my dilemma. What happens in /app/ - Theres a query, the query needs to get the ID from the url for example '3' And the query selects the data with the user_id 3, Then on the controller. It needs to get the data query result back

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your http request in Postman and it's working ok.

```
https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php?id=4235
```

and returns:

```
[
{
"firstname": "4235",
"lastname": "Round",
"profile_image": "jpg/55529055162cf0.jpg",
"lastname": "Round",
"iframe": "",
"media_format": "img",
"media_file_format": "jpg",
"media_post_id": "5851875bda5b3",
"media_author_id": "3",
"mediatxt": ""
},
{
"firstname": "4235",
"lastname": "Round",
"profile_image": "jpg/55529055162cf0.jpg",
"lastname": "Round",
"iframe": "",
"media_format": "img",
"media_file_format": "jpg",
"media_post_id": "583c459a745a4",
"media_author_id": "3",
"mediatxt": ""
},
{
"firstname": "4235",
"lastname": "Round",
"profile_image": "jpg/55529055162cf0.jpg",
"lastname": "Round",
"iframe": "",
"media_format": "img",
"media_file_format": "jpg",
"media_post_id": "583c4597778c1",
"media_author_id": "3",
"mediatxt": ""
},
{
}
]
```

so your error is:

$scope.session_id= sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');

if you print **$scope.session** you are going to get undefined. So your http request returns a empty array.

**Let's fix it**

> Inject sessionStorage. Let's suppose you are using ngStore, so you need to inject **$sessionStorage**.

Example:

```
.controller('feedCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$ionicHistory,$state,$http, $sessionStorage )
```

Change your code:

> $scope.session_id= sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');
>
> $http.get('https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php?id='+ $scope.session_id +).then(function(rest) {
>               $scope.records = rest.data;
>           });

to:

> $scope.session_id= $sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');

and delete + at the end of URL.

> $http.get('https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/feed_load.php?id='+ $scope.session_id).then(function(rest) {
>               $scope.records = rest.data;
>           });

As Jackk tell you.

Sorry for my english.